# Получение опыта на удаленке

Tags: мобильная-разработка

Всем привет! Я Junior iOS Developer и как вы знаете в городах, где 200-300 тысяч человек весьма всё печально с IT. То есть вакансий по нативной разработке там нет, видел пару раз вакансии по React Native и то с зарплатой мизерной. Знаю что из 5 вакансий в Москве могут пройти 2 точно. Вопрос такой у меня: Если работать на удаленке в команде, буду я получать опыт, тот который получают ребята в офисе? То есть там созвоны, вместе код ревью и тд делают и кажется всё океей, но что-то смущает из-за неопытности в данном вопросе. Стоит ли ехать в Москву для того, чтобы именно работать в офисе? Стоит это того? Какие плюсы если ты работаешь в офисе именно с командой, а не удаленно? Также пожалуйста добавьте тег "Обсуждение" под моим постом, а то я не нашел или не видит :/

Comment: Только надо учесть, что из-за коронавируса сейчас очень многие сидят на удалёнке, даже те, кто раньше всегда в офисе сидел.

Comment: @CrazyElf А я имел ввиду время до коронавируса, а так понятно что все сейчас на удаленке)

Answer (score 6):

В офисе в большинстве случаев будет лучше. Это зависит от многих факторов. Несколько плюсов офиса:

- рабочее настроение;
- удобная коммуникация;
- рабочая техника.

Дома Вас могут отвлекать куча факторов. Начиная от кота заканчивая семьей и друзьями. Также есть соблазн к лени( хоть не большой);

Вы можете подойти к более опытному сотруднику и спросить. А на удаленке в любом случае будут задержки. Также офисная жизнь в большинстве компаний - она по своему интересна. Шефы фирм заинтересованны в очных сотрудниках.

Вы не засоряете свою технику рабочим мусором. В случае поломки, Вам должны предоставить другую. Также обычно она настроена именно под работу

Удаленка - подходит хороша для тех, кто по определенным причинам не может сменить локацию, либо слишком часто их меняет.

Вывод: Я бы попробовал на Вашем месте поехать в более крупный город. Это хороший опыт будет для Вас в любом случае.